# Apache Commons Net IMAPsClient List Command

Tags: java, apache, imap

I'm trying to connect to `www.gmx.net` via the apache commons net ImapsClient

I'm able to log in and to fetch messages from folders i know.
but my problem is on listing folders.

JavaDoc tells me

> boolean   list(String refName, String mailboxName) Send a LIST command to the server.

whereat the RFC says send "" "*" to list all folders.
so if i call

```
imap.list("", "*");
```

the server returns me

> AAAB LIST  *
>
> AAAB BAD expected 1*ASTRING-CHAR / string instead of " "
>
> [AAAB BAD expected 1*ASTRING-CHAR / string instead of " "]

so if i call

```
imap.list("/", "*");
```

the server returns me

> AAAB LIST  *
>
> AAAB OK LIST completed
>
> [AAAB OK LIST completed]

but no folders get listed. As i can select folders `Inbox` and `Spamverdacht` there are obviously more than NO folders.

FULL log of one of this 'empty results' is:

> Using secure protocol: SSL
>
> Connecting to server imap.gmx.net on 993
>
> - OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN ENABLE ID IDLE LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS 
>     LITERAL+ MOVE NAMESPACE SASL-IR SORT SPECIAL-USE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT UIDPLUS 
>     UNSELECT WITHIN AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN] IMAP server ready H migmx029 104568 IMAP-0LaTV9-1ZTDW43mbH-00lcpb
>
> AAAA LOGIN *******
>
> AAAA OK LOGIN completed
>
> AAAB LIST / *
>
> AAAB OK LIST completed
>
> [AAAB OK LIST completed]
>
> AAAC LOGOUT
>
> - BYE Server logging out
>
> AAAC OK LOGOUT completed

whats my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it doesn't do proper escaping.

Try imap.list("\"\"", "\"*\""), that is put in escaped quotes.

Comment: you are right, i wonder that i had to add the " signs... thought it gets automatically added - which would make sense!